# What is the location of the configuration file in Neo4J 3.2?

Tags: neo4j

I just installed Neo4j 3.2.6 on Windows. I am trying to run `apoc.load.json`. I have moved the plugins folded. They really need to sort this out.

I run it and I'm getting this error:

> Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.load.json`: Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Import from files not enabled, please set
>   apoc.import.file.enabled=true in your neo4j.conf

only one problem, there is no `neo4j.conf`.

Database starts fine. I can run other statement, just not APOC procedures.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You can take a look in the [Neo4j file location docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/#file-locations). According to these docs the `neo4j.conf` file location in Windows installations is:

- `<neo4j-home>\conf\neo4j.conf` for zip installations
- `%APPDATA%\Neo4j Community Edition\neo4j.conf` for desktop installation (installer)

Answer (score 4):

For Neo4j Desktop,

1. Click pull down menu of your project
2. Click "Open Folder" menu
3. Click "Configuration"

[image: screenshot of Neo4j Desktop, choose the "Open" dropdown menu for your project DBMS]

Then new window of explorer will be opened with the path with `neo4j.conf` file included, for example:

```
C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Neo4j\Relate\Data\dbmss\dbms-3a5f5b9b-77b4-48cf-96f4-43aa81cce24b\conf\
```

Answer (score 3):

For Neo4j Desktop:

> C:\Users{user}\AppData\Roaming\Neo4j
>   Desktop\Application\neo4jDatabases\database-{YOUR DATABASE HERE}\installation-{version}\plugins

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to find in other directions, you can try searching in the below path where I found my configuration located:

> C:\Users\{user}\.Neo4jDesktop\neo4jDatabases\database-{YOUR DATABASE
>   HERE}\installation-{version}\conf

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the Neo4j documentation says that for windows desktop `neo4j.conf` file location is
`%APPDATA%\Neo4j Community Edition\neo4j.conf`, I couldn't find the file at that particular location.

I found the `neo4j.conf` file at below location :

`{YOUR_NEO4J_DB_DIRECTORY}\neo4jDatabases\database-{SOME_VERSION_STRING}\installation-{YOUR_NEO4J_VERSION}\conf`

Hope it helps someone!